# How to get list of related videos search by keyword using youtube api in android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get list of YouTube videos search by keyword in my app.
I refer many links but getting error at

```
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;

YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
              public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();
```

I get the following error message

```
The import com.google.api.services.samples cannot be resolved
```

Auth is not imported.
My Refer link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: what error you are getting post logcat details

Comment: @RQube thanks for reply,error is showing at                     import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;        error is The import com.google.api.services.samples cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You can search youtube videos by sending query url to Youtube API. you can search by category also. for code [ClickHere](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/04/getting-youtube-videos-using-youtube-api.html)

Comment: what are the libs are used to search videos.errors are showing:YouTubeService cannot be resolved to a type and can you provide any sample code to get list of videos related to search keyword

Comment: @user3331192 You have to use the gdata-youtube-2.0,gdata-client,gdata-core,gdata-media apis

Comment: give any sample code to get videos from youtube and play in own app